# Exercise 2.3.17 from Qing Liu

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is exercise 3.17 from Qing Liu's Alg.Geo. book.

Let $f:X\rightarrow Y$ be quasi-compact morphism of scheme. Let $\mathscr{J}=Ker f^{\sharp}$ and let $Z=V(\mathscr{J})$. Show that $Z$ is a scheme, that $Z$ have universal property of closure, and $f(X)$ is dense in $Z$.

I am quite stuck on this one. Can anyone help?

Comment: With which part you have a problem?

Comment: Quasi-compactness ensures that $\mathscr{J}$ is quasi-coherent. The construction of the closed ringed subspace $V(\mathscr{J})$ with underlying space $\mathrm{Supp}(\mathscr{O}_Y/\mathscr{J})$ and structure sheaf the inverse image of $\mathscr{O}_Y/\mathscr{J}$ is described in general early on in Liu's book. Quasi-coherence will help you show this is a closed subscheme of $Y$. Does that get you started?

Comment: @KeenanKidwell: thanks, it took me a few days, but I got it. QL did not define quasi-coherent (not yet anyway), but after looking this one up the technique has come up before.